# Not able to attach a HTML page to mail body in R

Tags: html, r, email, sendmailr

I am trying to add an HTML mail body. 'path_to_html' is clearly visible but I am not able to mail.

```
 library(mailR)
 library(R2HTML)
   heading <- c(
"<html>
<head>
<body>
<p> A new program </p></br>


</br>



</body>
</html>")

path_to_html <- "e:/mailer.html"

HTML(heading, file = path_to_html, append = TRUE)
  send.mail(from = "abc@xyz.com",to = mail_list,                                                           
        subject =  "Hi",
        body = path_to_html,
        html = TRUE,
        inline = TRUE,
        smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, user.name ="abc@xyz.com" , 
                    passwd = "XXXXXX", ssl = TRUE),
        authenticate = TRUE,
        attach.files = path_attach_pdf,
        send = TRUE)
```

I get the following error :

```
  Error in ls(envir = envir, all.names = private) : 
  invalid 'envir' argument
```

Comment: Have you [turned on access for less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)?

Comment: yeah. My local file is `path_to_html`. Suppose if I instead use `body= heading` alone. I am able to send the  mail

Comment: Is the file empty? (I had that error once with an empty string, which I passed on to the body parameter) If note: Also try `e:\\mailer.html`. And if that doesn't work, put the file into your working directory `getwd()` and try `mailer.html`.

Comment: sure. Will Try it now :)

Comment: @lukeA Sorry not working :( Unfortunately If I type the local address on my chrome it displays the desired output. But `body=path_to_html` is not working

Answer (score 0):

If you [turned on access for less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) for the Gmail account, over which you are sending (`foo@gmail.com` in the example below), then this works like a charm:

```
writeLines(text="<html><body><p>test</p></body></html>", tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".html"))
library(mailR)
send.mail(from = "<foo@gmail.com>",
          to = "<bar@gmail.com>",
          subject = "test",
          body = tf,
          html = TRUE,
          smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", 
                      port = 465, 
                      user.name = "foo", 
                      passwd = "password", 
                      ssl = TRUE),
          authenticate = TRUE,
          send = TRUE)
```

If you haven't turned it on, then you'll get

> invalid 'envir' argument

Comment: Though I did not use the above code. I got it working. My html file contains images too. In case if I store the images in a particular path, it is working. May be cos of the `getwd`. I need to figure it out to pull the file from anywhere. @lukeA thanx anyways. Your thought process gave me a clue.

Comment: @ShivaPrakash Yep, the [documentation states that](https://github.com/rpremraj/mailR): _"send.mail expects the images in the HTML file to be referenced relative to the current working directory."_

Comment: I have now have a different problem all together. Let us say I have two html files say `html_1` and 'html_2` in different directories. I need to append them. In the sense I need to combine them. Till now I am using `HTML(html_1, file =html_2, append = T)` Considering `html_2` is in the working directory. But I can't append the other way round. Any clues to go about it /